# what is the meaning of mnemonic and mimic exactly?

Tags: word-meaning

I'm reading a book about programming in C and have seen this two words for the first time `mnemonic` and `mimic`. so what means these words from programming perspective.

> The declaration of the pointer ip ,
>   `int *ip;`
>   is intended as a `mnemonic`; it says that the expression `*ip` is an int . The syntax of the
>   declaration for a variable `mimics` the syntax of expressions in which the variable might
>   appear. This reasoning applies to function declarations as well

Comment: More context would be helpful.  Could you quote the sentences in which you saw these words?

Comment: Mnemonic device for the five NAm Great Lakes. H - Huron. O - Ontario. M - Michigan. E - Erie. S - Superior. HOMES (The link I had was less than useless -- it was bad.) I grew up with this one, so I remembered it. [Mnemonic Strategies](http://psychology.jrank.org/pages/426/Mnemonic-Strategies.html)

Comment: I'd say they mean pretty much the same in or out of the programming context.

Comment: I think the point that the author is trying to make is that while, in reality, `ip` has type pointer-to-int - which might more naturally lead to the declaration `int* ip` - the syntactically equivalent form `int *ip` (read as "the thing pointed to by `ip` is an `int`") *mimics* how the variable would be de-referenced e.g. `int i = *ip` ("assign to `i` the integer pointed to by `ip`") - which may make it easier to *remember* where the `*` goes. It's perhaps not a big deal for simple declarations but may become more helpful for complex declarations (e.g. those involving pointers to functions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They have no special meaning in programming.  The dictionary definitions should be enough to help understand what the author is trying to say:

> [**MNEMONIC:**](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/mnemonic) something (such as a word, a sentence, or a song) that helps people remember something (such as a rule or a list of names)
>
> [**MIMIC**:](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/MIMIC) to create the appearance or effect of (something), to naturally look like (something)

It's possible that someone is using these words in a specific context so they have special meaning, but if so they would have to define that meaning.

For example, I could say that a software "mimic" is a program that *emulates* a secure website or application (like a bank website) in order to trick people into entering their passwords or other personal information.  But since this is not a standard definition of "mimic", to avoid confusion, I would first explain it to the reader.